# "Unexpected identifier" with 'import printWord from '../support/action/printWord’;'

Tags: node.js, cucumber, es6-modules, cucumberjs

I’m getting an error 'Unexpected identifier’ with "import printWord from '../support/action/printWord’;” …

Given.js

```
const { Given } = require('cucumber’);
import printWord from '../support/action/printWord’;
Given(/^I print the (\S+) word$/, printWord);
```

printWord.js

```
export default word => {
console.log('============' + word);
};
```

How can i able to fix the issue ?

NMP Version : 6.9.0
node Version : 10.16.0

Answer (score 0):

You can import it in below format:

```
import { PrintWord } from '../support/action/printWord’;
```

But before applying this logic, 1) make sure printWorld file should exists in the given path
2) printFile class should be declared in this format:

```
export class PrintWorld { -- Some code here }
```

3) Save file name using printWorld.ts

If you are not exporting any of the ts class, we will not be able to import that class outside the file (considering you are working using typescript)